# MySQL flipping a boolean only sets it to '0'

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL statement function that looks like this

```
function store_channel_toggle_view_only($id){
    $conn = sql_connect();
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE channels SET view_only='NOT view_only' WHERE id='$id'");
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    sql_disconnect($conn);
}
```

As expected, when the value in the database is `1` this statement turns it to a `0`, but for some reason when the value is already `0` the value no longer changes and stays as `0`.

In addition, I have also tried `view_only='!view_only'` with the same affect.

What is happening? And why is it happening? (Yes, I double checked, the column really is a boolean)

Comment: `'NOT view_only'` is a string value, is that really what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
view_only='NOT view_only'
```

That is a string!

```
view_only = NOT view_only
```

That is the actual **[NOT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_not)** operation  on the `view_only` column.

Comment: Ah thank you, I think I did try that in one attempt but I guess I simultaneously messed up in the syntax somewhere and it threw and error, well it works now thanks!

Comment: Evaluated in a numeric context, the string literal `'NOT view_only'` evaluates to `0`. As a simple demonstration... `SELECT 'NOT view_only' + 0`